# coreNLP feature ranking for sentimental analysis

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using coreNLP library for sentimental analysis. I have a Amazon data set and when I pass to using the command mentioned below it only results values like 0(negative or neutral) or 1(positive, very positive). I want to modify the existing code for sentiment to return multiple values for example (0= negative, 1= neutral, 2= positive, 3=very positive)

and calculate the maximum of positive I received, maximum of very positive I received and decide whether the sentiment is positive or negative or very positive. How can I achieve this? Most of the files are in jar format and I am not sure how can i make the code change for the above requirement to achieve the result.

Downloaded coreNLP package code from [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html)

Comment: Currently when I pass a file to the sentiment pipeline I get sentiment like 0 or 1 as neutral/negative/very negative/positive/very positive. I want to count the number of sentiment category and the maximum number of count will decide the overall score. My question: 1. Where should in code I make the change to get the rank as 0,1,2,3,4 as opposed to 0 and 1? 2. Is there any custom coreNLP module API i can use to count the number of sentiment type(exp: very positive occurred 5 times , postive-3 times and so the overall score is very positive for the dataset)?

Comment: I guess there is no API available. So I have written my own custom function to map the sentiments to the different custom values. If anyone have any better method please let me know.